# Xamarin Package(s) aren't installing. What setting am I missing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, portable-class-library

I'm having issues understanding how I should setup my "target framework .NET portable"
I'm using the latest version of visual studio for MAC.

Here's the warning message I get.  I'm having a tough time understanding the what setting I'm missing

```
Checking compatibility for Rx-PlatformServices 2.3 with .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259.
Package Rx-PlatformServices 2.3.0 is not compatible with portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259). Package Rx-PlatformServices 2.3.0 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile136)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile78)
  - sl5 (Silverlight,Version=v5.0)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp71 (WindowsPhone,Version=v7.1)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
```

## PCL Settings

[image: Current Settings]

Comment: FYI - I don't recommend using this package. The owner of Rx-Platform has unlisted this package which could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.
 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-PlatformServices/2.3.0#

Comment: Try profile 7 and install packages again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rx-PlatformServices 2.3 NuGet package doesn't support PCL Profile 259.

## Easy Solution

Change your PCL Profile to `Profile78`

## Recommended Solution

Remove the PCL project and create a new Netstandard 2.0 project to replace it.

Netstandard is relatively new and it has replaced PCLs, which are now deprecated.

Comment: The Profile78 worked great.  I tried moving it to the Netstandard but there were too many other library conflicts.  Thanks Brandon